# bar plot - lollipop charts - vizualization

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar plot using this dataset below

```
df = structure(list(Affiliation = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("BMI", "CCS", 
"CS", "Epi", "Genom", "HSE", 
"HSR", "HPR"), class = "factor"), 
    count = structure(c(4L, 21L, 14L, 20L, 11L, 13L, 19L, 15L, 
    5L, 22L, 17L, 24L, 9L, 12L, 18L, 16L, 1L, 10L, 7L, 23L, 2L, 
    3L, 8L, 6L), .Label = c("15", "26", "27", "32", "40", "41", 
    "42", "58", "62", "63", "70", "88", "89", "96", "99", "112", 
    "125", "160", "164", "172", "176", "178", "200", "628"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2014", 
    "2015", "2016"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Affiliation", 
"count", "Year"), row.names = c(NA, 24L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I have done so far

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Affiliation, y = count, fill = Year, group = Year)) + 
    geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), stat = "identity", alpha = 1, 
    size = 1, width = 0.05) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = count), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
    vjust = -0.25) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

However I am trying to create a visualization for this bar plot based on this example:

[image: example]

which was discussed in this post: [Looking for better way to visualise distribution in R and ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536354/looking-for-better-way-to-visualise-distribution-in-r-and-ggplot2/35540620)

Comment: Where is `bgcolor` defined? And what exactly is the question here?

Comment: What is `bgcolor`? Chop it out and it runs. Also, if you set a `data` parameter in `ggplot`, you don't need to use `$`-notation; you can just put the unquoted variable name.

Comment: @alistaire, thanks alistaire I used `bgcolor` to make the background transparent. I have removed that now. I agree with you on the use of $

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm still not completely sure what your question is. The example that creates the lollipop charts does not use `geom_bar()`. Is this what you're after?

```
# Why did you have this as a factor?
df$count <- as.numeric(as.character(df$count))

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(Affiliation, count)) 
gg <- gg + geom_segment(aes(xend=Affiliation, yend=0))
gg <- gg + geom_point()
gg <- gg + geom_text(aes(label=count, y=count+25), vjust=0, size=3)
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0, 800))
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~Year)
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(strip.background=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(strip.text=element_text(hjust=0))
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.minor.y=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=8))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=8, vjust=c(0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)))
gg
```

[image]

Even after the comment reply it's still not clear what you are after.

```
gg <- ggplot(df) 
gg <- gg + geom_segment(aes(x=Year, y=count, xend=Year, yend=0, color=Year), show.legend=FALSE)
gg <- gg + geom_point(aes(x=Year, y=count, color=Year))
gg <- gg + geom_text(aes(label=count, x=Year, y=count+40), vjust=0, size=3)
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0, 800))
gg <- gg + ggthemes::scale_color_tableau(name="")
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~Affiliation, nrow=1, scales="free_x")
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(strip.background=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(strip.text=element_text(hjust=0))
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.minor.y=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=8))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=8, vjust=c(0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)))
gg <- gg + theme(legend.key=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="bottom")
gg
```

[image]